# Is it possible to detect if a link has been disabled by JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-selectors

I'm familiar with adding .preventDefault() (and return false) to a link to stop a link from following through, but does anyone know of a way to check if a link has been set to preventDefault (and/or return false)?

Example in mockJS:

```
$('a').not().preventDefault().click(function() {
  //report that the link has been clicked
}
```

NOTE: I don't know if/what script might be added that stops a link from following it's default behavior.

Thanks,
Steve

Comment: What do you mean by active/disabled? You mean being clicked on like the psuedoclass :active? Or...?

Comment: I mean a live link. One that hasn't been told to return false or disable the default behavior.

Answer (score 1):

one option would be to apply another class to each type of "link" that you have (carousels, tabs, a hrefs, etc.) and then change your click handler for tracking to be `$('linkClass').click(function() {.....});`

EDIT: My point here is not that you should only, necessarily, use one extra class, but perhaps using classes as flags here for your links as a way of tracking them would be best for you. Without seeing your entire code, I really can't tailor this to your need, so I kept it pretty generic for you.

EDIT 2: I just want to clarify this idea a little bit better.

What you would do is set up a selector for your links (this selector may have to watch a few different IDs, classes, etc in order to do this). Add a click event handler to that selector and then each time one of those links is clicked you will add track flags in the form of classes, so as to facilitate your track code.

Example:

```
var $links = $(...[selector stuff]...);
$links.click(function() {
    var $this = $(this);
    $this.addClass("clicked");
    ...do clicked stuff...
    $this.addClass("isActive");
    ...do active stuff...
    $this.removeClass("isActive").addClass("visited");
    ...do visited stuff...
});
```

By using this technique, you are also able to later check and see which links have been clicked, in case some or all of your tracking method(s) run outside of the click event handler.

The other great thing about this technique is the low amount of overhead with respect to the addition and removal of classes. Many people are surprised at how little overhead there is because they instinctively think of styles when they think of classes. However, classes are one of the most useful attributes for an element and so long as you are not adding or removing styles your overhead with be very minimal (using classes for flags is also a very common practice with .NET development).

Comment: I have a very large code base running this site, and I can't add a class to links, etc. My ability to know what I want to track has to be delivered by JS, and while I will be more specific than $('a), I won't know up front if the link has been disabled or not.

Comment: okay, so let me just clarify before I respond: do you mean that you cannot use JS to programmatically mark "links" that have been clicked with an additional class as you click them (very little overhead, suprisingly, because you're just applying a class without styles - a flag), or do you mean that you cannot add a class to all of your links ahead of time? I may not have been clear in my original solution so I'll try to clarify

Comment: I can't add classes to all my links ahead of time, and adding a class after/during the click wont work because I'll have already tracked the click.

Comment: Zachary, I think I've lost the initial question in the details. I'm going to see if I can't edit the original question to see if I can clear things up a little.